# 4.99 showing up as 499 - Converting BIGINT into Decimals

Tags: mysql, decimal, bigint

The problem I am having is that my output is not being displayed correctly. For example, what should display 4.99 shows as 499. The amounts in my Stripe database are stored as BIGINT. I've tried using CAST but the decimal is input at the end of my values with trailing 00s and that is not what I want.

What I've tried:

```
SELECT COALESCE(card_address_country, card_country) AS "Country", 
SUM(CAST(amount AS DECIMAL(19,2))) AS "Total Revenue"
FROM charges
WHERE amount_refunded = 0 and paid = true
GROUP BY COALESCE(card_address_country, card_country)
ORDER BY SUM(amount) DESC
```

[image]

$293,839,799 should be $2,938,397.99 and $499 = $4.99.

I've tried dividing the amounts by 100 but it results in a round whole number and the sum is no longer calculated correctly.

```
SELECT COALESCE(card_address_country, card_country) AS "Country", 
SUM(amount/100) AS "Total Revenue"
FROM charges
WHERE amount_refunded = 0 and paid = true
GROUP BY COALESCE(card_address_country, card_country)
ORDER BY SUM(amount) DESC
```

[image]

Is what I am trying to achieve possible? Or am I just using the wrong functions? I was thinking it could be the way the database has been setup as well.

Comment: You'll have to cast AND divide. `SUM(CAST(amount as DECIMAL(19,2))/100.00)) as "Total Revenue"` should do the trick.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much.

Comment: Show us a `CREATE TABLE`, one `INSERT` and one `SELECT` that demonstrate the problem.  It sounds like you stored cents in an `INT`?